# Writing code to interface with another system

Tags: event-observer, web-services

I'm building a magento store which needs to interface with another system and I could use some guidance.

Although not particularly relevant, I'm communicating with the 'other' system using web services (it's on another server) but what I need help with is finding the places where I need to put in code to do what I want.

There are three major functions that I need to implement:-

1. When a user clicks on the product detail page I need to make a call to check the stock levels on the other system, update (if changed) the magento stock levels and THEN display the product detail page.
2. When a sale is completed, I need to send details of that sale to the other system.
3. When a new product is added I need to communicate with the other system.  This may be a bit more complex because there are a few checks I need to do during the 'add product' process, for example, check the SKU is valid, that the product doesn't already exist on the other system, etc.  I think until I start coding this I shan't realise the full extent of this functionality!

Any guidance gratefully received!  Although I'm very experienced with programming, web , PHP, etc. my Magento experience is fairly limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event-observers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).
Let's take them one by one:

1. Product view. You can use the event `catalog_controller_product_init`. This event is dispathced after the product is loaded and before any output is shown. You need something like this:

   ```
   public function productInitAfter($observer) 
   {
       $product = $observer->getProduct();
       //do your api call here and update the $product
   }
   ```

   But I wouldn't recommend this approach. Imagine the number of calls you will make to the api and most of them will be for nothing, because most probably nothing changes every 5 seconds. Instead I would create [a cron](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job) that will run from time to time and update the product attributes you need.
2. You can use the event `checkout_submit_all_after`. this is dispatched when the cart is converted to an order. you can use something like this:

   ```
   public function checkoutSubmitAllAfter($observer) 
   {
       //get the order object 
       $order = $observer->getOrder();
       //if you are on multishipping checkout there might be multiple orders
       $orders = $observer->getOrders();

       //you can get the details from the order or orders and send them to the api.
   }
   ```
3. You can use the event `catalog_product_save_before`. this is dispatched (as you expect) before saving the product.  Use something like this:

   ```
   public function beforeSaveProduct($observer) 
   {
       $product = $observer->getProduct();
       //send the product data to the API
       //in case something is wrong and the product should not be saved for some reason you can just throuw an exeption.
       //lets say that $response is what you get from the API call
       if ($response->getErrorMessage()) {
           Mage::throwException($response->getErrorMessage()); 
       }
   }
   ```

your needs are kind of broad and depend on the API so I cannot come up with a full functioning code, but I think the ideas are there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Marius.  I realise that I'm asking rather general questions but then I'm after general answers at this stage, how to start and where to start looking.

I may well end up using cron jobs to achieve some of this functionality though I'm hoping that the check of stock will be very quick; a single call will get all stock values for all products within the configurable group so I'm hoping the impact will not be severe.

I'd worked out that I'd need to implement some event observers but there seemed to be hundreds to choose from!

Comment: I don't know your level of experience with Magento, but the best place to start in my opinion is to check how event observers work. That's the first link I posted in the answer. They are the most non-intrusive way to change the behavior of the application. You cannot do everything with observers, but I think that all 3 points you asked can be covered via observers.